# Does FileSystemObject know that a file is incomplete?

Tags: asp-classic, ftp, filesystems

Yes, I'm still using Classic ASP.

I'm about to write a script that checks a directory on the server, every 5 minutes, for newly uploaded photos, by my office, and to transfer the photos to another location. I'm using ASP and the FileSystemObject as the application and a Windows Schedule calls it.

What I would like to know is: If the user is sending 150 photos, by FTP, my application is not going to know if the user has finished uploading, or not. So then the application will go through the files one-by-one and transfer them. If my user has a slower connection than the speed of my application, the script may eventually come across the file that is currently being uploaded...

Will my application grab that file thinking it's complete or will it know that it's in the middle of upload and leave it alone? If it DOES grab it and transfers half a photo, how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Martin, The FSO won't see a file until it is completely uploaded.

Comment: BTW, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I take it you removed my salutations then John? I didn't realise I actually included one. Sometimes I do, sometimes I don't..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to test for that, much depends on how the uploader is working.

Its highly unlikely that a file currently open for write access while the uploader creates it is going to allow your code to move it.  An attempt to move it will result in a sharing violation or similar error.  So protecting that section of code with an `On Error Resume Next` would do it.  Have your code skip that file in the knowledge that it will be picked up again when the next poll comes round.